# Windows 8: Search entire computer?

Tags: windows-8, windows-search

I am running Windows 8.

I would like to search the entire harddrive for a file named `cookies.sqlite`. I am searching for files which belong to a missing Firefox profile.

If I open the Charms Bar, select "Search", select "Files" and search for `cookies.sqlite`, then Windows says "No files match your search". Yet, I can browse to `%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\` and see the file `cookies.sqlite`. The file exists, but Windows search isn't finding it.

How can I use Windows to search for a file on my computer?

Comment: Try using Everything - http://www.voidtools.com/

Comment: What if you open Computer and search from the Search text box there ?

Comment: @Ofiris : That works. K.A. also suggested it in the answer below.

Comment: I think I might like that Everything... much faster when searching specifically for a file by name than I expected it to be. Thanks @HackToHell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the Desktop, open File Explorer. Navigate to the root of the hard drive in question. Type in "cookies.sqlite" in the search box (upper right of window, just below the ribbon). This should search the entire drive.